# Zoom past ImageView bounds

Tags: ios, swift

I've been following an article that shows how to reproduce Instagrams zoom on images. It works fine, but when I zoom, the image does not go past the bounds of the ImageView. As you can see in the Screenshot this looks odd, and I would like it to be as it is on Instagram, with the Image zooming to the whole screen if needed, and snapping back on release (which is already working).

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this? Below are the pinch and pan functions. 
Thanks in advance

```
@objc func pan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if self.isZooming && sender.state == .began {
        self.originalImageCenter = sender.view?.center
    } else if self.isZooming && sender.state == .changed {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self)
        if let view = sender.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                                  y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        }
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.imageView.superview)
    }
}

@objc func pinch(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "disablePage"), object: nil)

    if sender.state == .began {
        let currentScale = self.imageView.frame.size.width / self.imageView.bounds.size.width
        let newScale = currentScale*sender.scale
        if newScale > 1 {
            self.isZooming = true
        }
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        guard let view = sender.view else {return}
        let pinchCenter = CGPoint(x: sender.location(in: view).x - view.bounds.midX,
                                  y: sender.location(in: view).y - view.bounds.midY)
        let transform = view.transform.translatedBy(x: pinchCenter.x, y: pinchCenter.y)
            .scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
            .translatedBy(x: -pinchCenter.x, y: -pinchCenter.y)
        let currentScale = self.imageView.frame.size.width / self.imageView.bounds.size.width
        var newScale = currentScale*sender.scale
        if newScale < 1 {
            newScale = 1
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: newScale, y: newScale)
            self.imageView.transform = transform
            sender.scale = 1
        }else {
            view.transform = transform
            sender.scale = 1
        }
    } else if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .failed || sender.state == .cancelled {
        guard let center = self.originalImageCenter else {return}
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.imageView.center = center
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.isZooming = false

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "enablePage"), object: nil)

        })
    }
}


 func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to set [`.clipsToBounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds) to false, either in code or there's a checkbox in Interface Builder.